# Need to use my .ssh_config once exporting a new $HOME

Tags: bash, git, ssh

I'm in a remote session that needs to access a particular github domain. I can't utilize git on this machine until I export $HOME as the value I set it as. Once I'm in this location - how can I utilize my previous ssh_config file?

Comment: `ssh -F <config_file_location>`

Comment: though this isn't what I was looking for - it taught me something new! ty!

Answer (score 0):

As @jordanm suggested, you could use `ssh -F /path/to/ssh/config`, but the problem with that is that it might not pick up your implicit public/private key pair from your ssh configuration directory which is likely what you're trying to do.

What I would suggest instead is rather than trying to specify a different SSH configuration, you update your SSH configuration in `$HOME/.ssh/config` to add that a specific host entry and specify the correct private key file there. This would be done like so:

```
Host youraliashere
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile /path/to/private/key/id_rsa
```

Then you'd just use the remote you configured over SSH for git, something like this (without `<` and `>` of course):

```
git remote set-url origin git@<youraliashere>:<username>/<repo>
```